# Need help closing a automatically opening internet explorer web page

Tags: python-3.x, windows-10

I have looked extensively through this site and through other sites and modified my code to close my internet explorer page but it will just open and will not close.This is the code.

```
import webbrowser
import os
webbrowser.open('https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BByMzI1YjKA')
browserExe = "iexplore"
os.system("taskkill /f /im "+browserExe)
```

It doesn't give me any error messages but I can't close the browser, any help is much appreciated
By the way I'm on windows 10 using python 3.5.1

Comment: I don't know windows, but I think `/im` must be the full name of the executable (`iexplore.exe`), or you could try a glob pattern: `/im iexplore*`

Comment: Do you get any error message? Does the command `taskkill /f /im iexplore` work if you try it directly in the shell? The default browser in windows 10 is not internet explorer, but Edge. Are you sure that's not the problem?

Comment: It's not hugely important as my code doesn't need to have music in the background but it would work well as it's a music quiz which i'm going to incorporate into it.

Comment: If you tried `iexplore.exe` and it didn't work, why did you accept that as an answer? I don't understand.

Comment: I tried with other variations of the codes I found but it didn't work so I ask on here and he said to put .exe and using my knowledge I tweaked my code to get it to work, so he helped close it which was the question so any error messages are out of the scope of this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The task (internet explorer) doesn't get killed, because the task 'iexplore' doesn't exist. If you open an internet explorer window, it will get the taskname 'iexplore.exe'.

So change this:

```
browserExe = "iexplore"
```

to this:

```
browserExe = "iexplore.exe"
```

Sincerly,
Chris Fowl

Comment: Thank you for that, it modified the code and it now works.